# The problem of matching consecutive cross-line strings

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have a file named "s0.log",There's a lot of this structure in there:
[image]

You can see that the strings "Alpha occ.eigenvalues --" and "Alpha virt.eigenvalues --" will be contiguous.

There are many similar structures in the file, and my current need is to find the data in the last one of these structures

```
Clear["Global`*"];
(*set current dir*)
SetDirectory[
  NotebookDirectory[]
  ];


s0Log = Import["https://vip.123pan.cn/1812087188/tmp/Mathematica/s0.log", \
{"Text", "Lines"}]
```

I don't know how to match this situation of consecutive lines, I consulted ChatGPT and checked the regular expression, but I still don't know how to deal with it

Comment: For any serious _Mathematica_ programming, please, forget about ChatGPT.

Comment: @xzczd Some of the regulars I can't think of are better with ChatGPT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = Import[(*address*), {"Text", "Lines"}];

tf = StringContainsQ[lst, "virt"];

pos = Last@SequencePosition[tf, {False, True}]
(* {9976, 9977} *)

lst[[pos]]
(* {" Alpha  occ. eigenvalues --   -0.21583  -0.20116  -0.17412", 
    " Alpha virt. eigenvalues --   -0.03836  -0.02637  -0.01939  -0.01479  -0.01105"} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets suppose we have this fake data generator

```
fakedata = StringJoin[MapThread[
   StringRepeat[
     StringTemplate["`` -- ``\n"][#1, 
      StringRiffle[RandomReal[2, 2]]], #2] &, {RandomWord[3], 
    RandomInteger[{2, 5}, 3]}]]
```

which produced this fakeData:

```
(*
rumbling -- 1.64122 1.04449
rumbling -- 1.64122 1.04449
comic -- 1.79106 0.386783
comic -- 1.79106 0.386783
comic -- 1.79106 0.386783
comic -- 1.79106 0.386783
comic -- 1.79106 0.386783
philatelist -- 1.07391 0.473677
philatelist -- 1.07391 0.473677
philatelist -- 1.07391 0.473677
*)
```

We can use this function to extract the last chuck.

```
extractLastChunk =
  RightComposition[

    (* split input string by lines *)
    OperatorApplied[StringSplit]["\n"],
    
    (* group lines by the string before -- in each line *)
    OperatorApplied[SplitBy][StringSplit[#, "--"][[1]] &],

    (* take last group *)
    Last,

    (* convert back into a string *)
    OperatorApplied[StringRiffle]["\n"]
  ]
```

This is the result of applying it:

```
extractLastChunk[fakedata]
```

```
(*
philatelist -- 1.07391 0.473677
philatelist -- 1.07391 0.473677
philatelist -- 1.07391 0.473677
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[0];

data =
 StringJoin@
  MapThread[
   StringRepeat[StringTemplate["`` -- ``\n"][#1, StringRiffle[RandomReal[2, RandomInteger[{2, 3}]]]], #2] &, 
   {RandomWord[3], RandomInteger[{2, 5}, 3]}]
```

[image]

```
d = StringSplit @ data;

p = SequencePosition[d, {_, "--", __?(StringMatchQ[#, NumberString] &)}]
```

{{1, 5}, {6, 10}, {11, 15}, {16, 20}, {21, 25}, {26, 29}, {30,
33}, {34, 37}, {38, 41}}

```
StringRiffle /@ Last @ GatherBy[Take[d, #]& /@ p, First]
```

{"boasting -- 0.523171 1.23304", "boasting -- 0.523171 1.23304"}